# Can't extend EventEmitter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I'm trying to create a custom event emitter. It seems that I can't replace `on` and `emit`, like below.

- I've tried assigning the methods to other variables and using those, and deleting the originals (does not work)
- I've tried assigning `on` and `emit` to different methods like `onTest` and `emitTest` (which works)

Here's the class that extends `EventEmitter`:

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events'

export default class MyEventEmitter extends EventEmitter {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this._on = this.on
    this._emit = this.emit
    delete this.on
    delete this.emit
  }
  on () {
    this._on.apply(this, Object.values(arguments))
  }
  emit () {
    this._emit.apply(this, Object.values(arguments))
  }
}

let event = new MyEventEmitter()

event.on('hi', () => console.log('meow'))

event.emit('hi')
```

Here's the stack:

```
$ babel-node ./src/event-store/my-event-emitter.js 
/Users/thomas/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/es7.object.values.js:0



RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.propertyIsEnumerable (native)
    at /Users/thomas/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/_object-to-array.js:12:32
    at values (/Users/thomas/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/es7.object.values.js:7:12)
    at MyEventEmitter.emit (my-event-emitter.js:15:28)
    at MyEventEmitter.emit (my-event-emitter.js:15:16)
    at MyEventEmitter.emit (my-event-emitter.js:15:16)
    at MyEventEmitter.emit (my-event-emitter.js:15:16)
    at MyEventEmitter.emit (my-event-emitter.js:15:16)
    at MyEventEmitter.emit (my-event-emitter.js:15:16)
    at MyEventEmitter.emit (my-event-emitter.js:15:16)
```

*UPDATE 1*

Also tried this and received the same error:

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events'

export default class MyEventEmitter extends EventEmitter {
  constructor () {
    super()
  }
  on () {
    this.on.apply(this, Object.values(arguments))
  }
  emit () {
    this.emit.apply(this, Object.values(arguments))
  }
}

let event = new MyEventEmitter()

event.on('hi', () => console.log('meow'))

event.emit('hi')
```

Comment: "*I've tried assigning the methods to other variables and using those*" - **Why?** Just don't do that.

Comment: "*deleting the originals*" - (again, why?) You cannot do that, as they are prototype methods.

Comment: @Bergi are you suggesting the contents of what I just put in the code block within `UPDATE 1`?

Comment: Not exactly, they should be `super` calls. See my answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempts at redefining these inherited methods ended up with `this._emit === this.emit`, which in turn produced infinite recursion in a call.

If you want to overwrite methods, you should just do so. No need to reassign them to other names or try to delete properties that the instances don't even have.

```
export default class MyEventEmitter extends EventEmitter {
  on(...args) {
    return super.on(...args)
  }
  emit(...args) {
    return super.emit(...args);
  }
}
```

<sub>(I suppose those `Object.values` calls were meaningless)</sub>

Comment: What do I do here if I do want to set `this` properties in the constructor? There's no way to do that without calling super.

Comment: @ThomasReggi: Sure, that's not a problem. I just omitted the default constructor here as you had not yet created custom properties.

Comment: But I can't have a `constructor()` and set a this property without calling super. Throws this error `'this' is not allowed before super()`.

Comment: Yes, just call `super()`! Why would you avoid it?